# Merging mySQL database with PHP while maintaining field

Tags: php, mysql

Background: A group of students including me are creating a website for a merit system for our school. We basically had no experience in html, css, php or sql databases at the start. I will say we've managed decently.

However, we've run into a problem with updating the database. Every week, we need to merge the table for students from a csv, which is updated with classes and all from a department of education system. So there are thousands of students and each of them have certain details that when updated can change but others that need to stay the same. For example, we have the number of merits which needs to stay the same when we update but details such as their year group or classes can change. The thing is, is that this update is done of a csv file which may also have new students that need to be updated to the database and the csv is not in any order. So we are trying to find a solution which allows one field to be the same but allow others to change.

So we've tried LOAD DATA INFILE with a unique key but the problem we found was that while it preserved the merits, it ignored the other details and just added new students.

EDIT: So the students have a class field which contains the classes of the student. When we import, we need to be able to change that but still maintain the merit field which will not be in the csv file. We understand that we could just manually import it but suspect that will take a long time to run.

Our code will be in PHP by the way.

tl;dr
Need to find out how to merge/import databases from csv, changing only specific fields of existing students and also adding new students

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the long post. This is my first post so do forgive me if I make any mistakes.

Comment: Your question is vague and unclear. Please take the time to revise it: use the `edit` link and describe _exactly_ what you actually mean. What do you mean by "changing one specific field"? What do you mean by "import a database"?

Comment: Your old values were unchanged including the merits(they were not "preserved" as per your expectations) because the records were likely skipped or query was not executed on those records due to PK constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a php script which **reads the contents of the file**, line by line preferably since it is a CSV. You will then need to use the primary key unique identifier from each CSV line to **check whether a record with that primary key value already exists in the database**. **If a record with that primary key exists in the database, use the *UPDATE* query** to update the merits only. **If a record cannot be found with that primary key, use the *INSERT* statement** to add that new record to the database.

**NOTE:** Bolded bits are steps required, in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With regards to the php script, with thousands of students with maybe 8 fields each, would the script take long to execute?

Comment: You would have to do all the inserts in one insert statement, and all the updates using prepared statements perhaps, for this script to execute in a reasonable amount of time. You may also need to tweek mysql and php configurations to accommodate such an operation i.e memory usage, allowed packet size, etc.